# jQuery multi draggable and multi sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to use jQuery draggable and sortable together. Below is the explanation why:

I have two listboxes, `A` and `B`. I want to drag and drop multiple items at once from one listbox to another. The `B` listbox needs to be sortable at the same time, that means if I am dragging multiple items from `A`, I can place them at any position in `B`. I want to do internal sorting on `B` as well (multiple items at the same time).

Listbox `A` however, is not sortable, so I cannot sort the items inside it, and when I am dragging from `B`, I can only append it to `A`, not sort it. (or rather move it to their original position, before dragging to `B`)

Hope I've explained it clearly. Have been trying since 2 days, and didn't find any answer on the web as wel.

Comment: I assume you are using draggable, droppable and sortable from jQuery UI here, is that correct?

Comment: Actually - what do you mean by a listbox? <select multiple> ?

Comment: yeh its jQuery UI. and by listbox i mean <select multiple>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself.

The key is to use the first listbox 'A' as draggable with connectedList to "B", and use the second listbox "B" as sortable.

Multiple sortable items effect can be acheived in the "start" and "stop" event handlers, and combining/separating the selected items.